# HTML5 <input type="number"> customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a HTML5 input box (**type=number**). My requirement is that the user should be able to set the value only through UP & DOWN arrow (spinners). User shouldn't be able to enter the value manually. Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="listitem in listitems">
  <input id="qtyinput" style="width:70px;" type="number" ng-model="listitem.qty" placeholder="Quantity" min='1' value='1'>
</tr>
```

Comment: only through up down arrow ... like on the keyboard, or a visual up / down arrow they click?

Comment: only using UP & DOWN arrow that comes with HTML5 <input type="number">

Comment: the spinners, got it.

Comment: @ShouryaSharma did you try the solution I already suggested?

Comment: i did. it's not working. i'm looking for - 'why it is not working' as it's working fine in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7q5Aq/1/

Comment: What might be the rationale for wanting this?

Comment: I'm making a POS app in node-webkit. In kiosk mode, I need to disable all the elements wherein keyboard entries are possible. (It'll only be used either by **mouse** or **touch**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
$('input[type="number"]').keydown(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

For AngularJS specific solution you can create a custom directive:

```
angular.module('demo')
.directive('disableKeyboard', function () {
  return function (scope, el) {
    el.keydown(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }); 
  };
});
```

And apply it by:

```
<input disable-keyboard type="number">
```

Comment: really? jQuery? cant you just make the bloody input readonly?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea by making the input readonly how would you be able to change its value using the arrows?

Comment: thats y i asked my question ... up and down arrow on the keyboard, or a visual up / down that they click? the spinners arent produced cross-browser, if you rely on them you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @MinkoGechev nvm, looks like the spinners only are his requirement, upvoted ur answer.

Comment: @MinkoGechev You can also use `event.preventDefault()` if the `return false` doesn't work. Some additional [info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).

Comment: @GaurangTandon thanks for your suggestion and the link. The answer is fixed.

Comment: Apart from being dependent on JavaScript, and hence trivially overridable, this method means that a person who cannot use a mouse cannot use the control at all, not even using keys that would activate the spinner. So whatever the real disease (the original problem) might be, this cure must be worse than the disease.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I agree but the code above fulfills completely the requirements in the question. And btw, "Unicode explained" is a great book. :-)